# Tracking button click on list view from a server. Android- Java

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am using AsyncResponse to get data from a database that is hosted on a server. I am using that data as venues in a list view that are clickable. After the user clicks a venue it will direct them to the venue's page pointed to by the VenueID. My question is what is the best way to tack which venue was clicked and how to pass that information to another class that will display the venue's page activity? Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {
private ArrayList<GetVenue> venuelist;
private ListView lvVenue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    Button mapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.location);
    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainMenu.this, this);
    taskRead.execute("my url");

    //Map button - open map page
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MapActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

public void OnClickVenue (View view){
  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent appInfo = new Intent(MainMenu.this, VenueActivity.class);
    startActivity(appInfo);
}
@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {

    venuelist = new JsonConverter<GetVenue>().toArrayList(s, GetVenue.class);

    final BindDictionary<GetVenue> dict = new BindDictionary<GetVenue>();
/*    dict.addStringField(R.id.VenueID, new StringExtractor<GetVenue>(){
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(GetVenue venue, int position){
            return "" + venue.VenueID;
        }
   });*/

    dict.addStringField(R.id.VenueName, new StringExtractor<GetVenue>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(GetVenue venue, int position) {
            return venue.VenueName;
        }
    });
  /*  dict.addStringField(R.id.Phone, new StringExtractor<GetVenue>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(GetVenue venue, int position) {
            return venue.Phone;
        }
    });*/


    FunDapter<GetVenue> adapter = new FunDapter<>
            (MainMenu.this, venuelist, R.layout.layout_main, dict);

    lvVenue = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVenue);
    lvVenue.setAdapter(adapter);



 /* On click of venue String, open Venue page*/

    lvVenue.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent appInfo = new Intent(MainMenu.this, VenueActivity.class);
            startActivity(appInfo);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnItemClick api return position of which item you click based on that you will get selected item by using list api get(position).

```
 lvVenue.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
            GetVenue getVenue = venuelist.get(position);//using position int get correspondig data
            Intent appInfo = new Intent(MainMenu.this, VenueActivity.class);
            startActivity(appInfo);
        }
    });
```

**GetVenue getVenue = venuelist.get(position);**

Comment: I made a toast to see the value of the position of the venue and it came back with '...GetVenue@8558be9' How could I use that information to build the next page specific for that venue? ie. pulling it's data from the database

Comment: GetVenuce@8558be9 is object , so you need to create method for print all the value in Getvenue method.

Comment: for more info see this https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method